# Access New Values for Other Tables in Transaction from Trigger

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to access the new values for inserted records in a transaction from a trigger on a different table in the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

When you cause a trigger to fire within a transaction the trigger runs in a nested transaction, so can see all the rows previously written in the transaction.

eg

```
create table t1(id int)

create table t2(id int)
go
create trigger tt2 on t2 after insert
as
begin
  select * from t1;
end
go

begin transaction
insert into t1(id) values (1)
insert into t2(id) values (1)
rollback
```

outputs

```
(1 row affected)
id
-----------
1

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
```

So you can see all the records in t1 from a trigger on t2, including any rows affected by the current transaction.  But there is no inherent way to tell which rows in t1 were affected by the current transaction.

And you could easily cause deadlocks doing this.

Answer (score 0):

A few possible solutions would be

1. create a column (`TransactionID UniqueIdentifier`) in both tables, generate a new GUID just after transaction has started and then insert that ID into both tables. Then, in a trigger, you get `TransactionID` from `Inserted`, and read the second table `WHERE TransactionID = ...` Consider indexes if those tables are large.
2. use `OUTPUT` clause for the first insert into some supplementary table. Use that table inside the trigger to know the new IDs from that transaction. Truncate that supplementary table just before committing the transaction. Don't use that table for any other processes / code.

PS. For (1), you can use `INT` or `BIGINT` for `TransactionID`, but you need to use some mechanism to generate a new unique ID